# Load report failed on client machine windows application

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application, windows, crystal-reports-2010

I am working on windows application and I am using crystal report for reporting. At the time of set  up creation i have also added merge module for crystal report. When I run the application in my machine and open the report ,it is working as expected.

For testing i have created simple report without any database connection with static content.

But when I install same set up on some other machine , I am getting Load report failed error from below line.

rpt.Load(path);

-- I have verified rpt file on path , it is there only.

Stack Trace

Load report failed.
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
   at MyApplicaion.frmreports.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

As i remember there is an option about the report to be included in the application. So when you send it to the client it is already included. I suppose this is your problem. Cannot remember exactly which but let me check. I think something like property file. Sorry for not the complete answer but there has been a long time since i used it.

Comment: Please check and let me know if you remember..  I have been trying to solve this issue but still not luck